# insert a date field mysql, struts2 spring hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, struts2, tomcat7

I'm working on a project using spring hibernate struts2 framework and MySQL database, I have a problem when I wanted to add a field of type `Date`
does not work, it means when I try to insert a `Date` field, it sends me this error:

```
WARNING: Error setting value
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setDATE_PANNE" failed for object model.Panne @ 1d055e2 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setDATE_PANNE ([Ljava.lang.String;)]

/ - Encapsulated exception ------------ \
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setDATE_PANNE ([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

**NB:** (DATE_PANNE -> this is the date fields) and setDATE_PANNE is the setter for this attribute. DATE_PANNE is of type date

apparently the problem is that struts2 has taken my `Date` as a `String` thing that he should not do.

I do not know how to convert and where?

Comment: Show code. Do you have a setter for the date? What are you sending for a date? Only String[] come from the request, struts2 not finding a suitable setter will display that error. If it could find a setter with the appropriate name, "setDATE_PANNE" is a pretty bad name btw... which takes a date then it would try to convert the String to a Date, it's nice like that.

Comment: At the very least the html parameter data and the action class.

Comment: Show us code and an example of how you write that `Date`. Struts usually converts automatically from `String` to `Date` if it detects the format (`MM-dd-yyyy` for example)

Comment: Date doesn't work, it's a true.

Comment: that's my code : my table in database mysql                           
id_panne         int(11) 
id_equipement         int(11)
description_panne  text  
cause_probable          text  
etat_panne          text  
date_panne          date 
defaillance          text  
effet                  text  
moyen_detection         text  
remarque                text

Comment: my classe (panne.java)   (.....)private java.util.Date  date_panne;


public java.util.Date getDate_panne() {
  return date_panne;
 }
 public void setDate_panne(java.util.Date date_panne) {
  this.date_panne = date_panne;
 }

Comment: ------------------panne.hbm.xml-------------
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="model.Panne" table="PANNE">
    <id name="id_panne" column="id_panne">
     <generator class="native">
    </generator>
   </id>
   <property name="id_equipement" column="id_equipement" type="long"/>
    `
     <property name="date_panne" column="date_panne" type="date" />
    <property name="defaillance" column="defaillance" type="string" />
    

   
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: it seems that struts2 has taken the date as a String thing that he should not do, if the solution is to convert before inserting thank you to tell me how to do it and where?

Comment: ----------------------------may page .jsp-------------
For insertion :
<s:form theme="simple" name="f" action="panneAction">
<label>Date panne</label><td><s:textfield  name="date_panne" id="date_panne" format="yyyy-MM-dd"/>  <s:submit     method="AjoutPanne" value="Ajouter" /></tr>
</table></s:form>

Comment: for display ( I don't have problem in this case )
<td>Date panne</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<s:iterator value="savedPanneList"><tr>
<td><s:date name="date_panne" format="yyyy-MM-dd" /></td>
<tr></s:iterator></tr></table>

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been working with struts 2 and have run into this ognl Exception a few times.  It seems to happen when you have a control on a JSP, such as an input checkbox named "checkBox", and a method from your controller (java class, not JSP) similarly named "setCheckBox()".  Somehow, behind the scenes, struts 2 or Ognl is generating a naming conflict and is unable to execute the correct method. Simply renaming either the control on the JSP (from my example from "checkBox" to "checkBox1") or renaming the method from the controller should solve your issue. Let me know if I did not elaborate enough. Hope this helps.

Regards,

Nick

Comment: thank you for your reply, I converted the date before inserting with this function : DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  date_panne = formatter.parse(this.date_panne1);
  panne.setDate_panne(date_panne);                                     and it works                                                               NB :date_panne1 is the field in jsp .